# simple search form data on multiply database using mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

i want to make a simple search data form on my website.. but how to connect on different database on mysqli and search the data? i have 12 database and all stucture database is same..

im trying using UNION but failed..
anyone have sample for me?

Answer (score 1):

In short: it is impossible in practice.

If you have all databases in one mysql instance, and you have user, who has access to all databases you should be able to use `UNION` like:

```
SELECT * FROM database1.table
UNION 
SELECT * FROM database2.table
```

This will probably end up connecting the results in the client...

Comment: I wrote: "it is impossible in practice." You can add user witch read access to all databases.

Comment: ok.. if i have user access for all database.. how to connect all database?

Comment: As usual. maybe without chose database. But choosed database shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: i m already try union but no error.. no result.. 
`if($search != "") {
require 'joindb.php';
  
$query = "(SELECT jobsNum FROM db1.jobs WHERE jobsNum = '$search')
UNION
(SELECT jobsNum FROM db2.jobs WHERE jobsNum = '$search')";

$result = $dbb->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 1) {`